# Change url of an existing project. and redirect to the new url

Tags: python, django

Everybody. I have a project in django. With a url that was changed

old url

```
http://domain/knowledge/schulung/agile-testing-for-the-whole-team
```

changed to:

```
http://domain/trainer/schulung/agile-testing-for-the-whole-team
```

the problem arises that there are users who already have url with /knowledge/. In django I want everyone who enters with the old url to be redirected to the new url.

try this method:

```
url(r'^knowledge/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/trainer/')),
```

this leads me to:

```
http://domain/trainer/
```

I need to go to :

```
http://domain/trainer/schulung/agile-testing-for-the-whole-team
```

Is there a method to do this?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Did you try `url(r'^knowledge/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/trainer/schulung/agile-testing-for-the-whole-team'))` ?

Comment: Can you add your ***old URL patters***?

Comment: They are url that will be generated by a slug and this has been sent to the cleintes by email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done by overriding the RedirectView and adding code in the `get_redirect_url` function:

A simple way of doing it would be:

```py
class KnowledgeRedirectView(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        useful_url_part = self.request.path.split('/knowledge/')[-1]
        return '/trainer/' + useful_url_part
```

Then you just have to relate this class based view with your initial url:

```py
url(r'^knowledge/', KnowledgeRedirectView.as_view()),
```

[RedirectView on Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview)

Comment: Thank you. I can't think of it this way, but my clients will be happy.